# \pgfsetfillopacity fails to work with mathematical fomula

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

I'd like to make some transparent effect with `\pgfsetfillopacity`(from `tikz`). It works all right with common text, but fails to work with mathematical fomulas, as the following fraction showes: number is in opacity, but the middle line not. How can I make all elements in a block have the transparent effect?

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pgfsetfillopacity{0.3}
text ok.\par
mathematical fomula: $\frac{1}{3}$ -- the middle line fails to have transparent effect.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is also a `\pgfsetstrokeopacity`

Comment: I don't think \pgf commands have any effect on normal text (outside of tikz or \pgftext).  I would use the opacity=pro package instead.

Comment: @ Tom `\pgfsetstrokeopacity` seems not work out of pgf enviroment. Or would you show me example?

Comment: Could you offer a MWE about what you want to do. Cause in your current example it does not have pgf enviroment at all.

Comment: Please see the attached figure which is typeset by my MWE. And `\pgfsetfillopacity` can work without `pgf` enviroment. However, when it works on mathimatical fomula in my example, only numbers 1 and 3 have the transparent effect. The middle line of the fraction number fails to be transparent. I want all the element of fomula can be opacitied.

Comment: The line is a rule, uses current color, not font color. Same in text mode: try `\hrule`, then try `{\color{green}\hrule}`. A PDF Special for transparency at start of document might work. Or a package.

Comment: @Cicada `A PDF Special for transparency at start of document might work` Would you show me an example?

Comment: PGF/Tikz does that - see @Tom's answer. A rule is a (brush)stroke, with no fill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not quite sure about the command `\pgfsetstrokeopacity{}`, if it can be safely used outside pgf env. But this is actually worked：

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pgfsetfillopacity{0.3}\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.3}
text ok.\par
mathematical fomula: $\frac{1}{3}$ -- the middle line fails to have transparent effect.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

the opacity commands of pgf work also outside a tikzpicture, but they are geared towards drawing and so split fill and stroke opacity. For text a more lightweight solution is to use the transparent package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{transparent,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\transparent{0.3}
text ok.\par
mathematical fomula: $\frac{1}{3}$ -- the middle line fails to have transparent effect.
\end{document}
```